# My google heat map wont appear in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, geocoding, heatmap

I am new to jupyter notebook and want to create a heatmap based on locations.
I have created a google API key and my code looks like the following:
The only thing wrong is that it states "Ooops something went wrong!"

```
import gmaps
import math
gmaps.configure(api_key="My API Key")
location_columns = df[['latitude', 'longitude']]
location_tuples = [tuple(x) for x in location_columns.values]
fig = gmaps.figure()
fig.add_layer(gmaps.heatmap_layer(location_tuples))
fig
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out

Comment: Is it based on matplotlib?

Comment: @alec_djinn I have added %matplotlib inline and still doesn't display anything

Comment: Have you installed the gmaps plugin for jupyter? https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps try their basic example once you have installed the plugin and let me know if it works.

Comment: @alec_djinn I have execute this in a command line ! pip install gmaps
It states requirement has already been satisfied

Comment: From their documentation: Make sure that you have enabled widgets extensions to Jupyter:

`$ jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension`
You can then install gmaps with:

`$ pip install gmaps`
Then tell Jupyter to load the extension with:

`$ jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix gmaps`  Have you done that?

Comment: @alec_djinn do i just run that in the notebook in any cell? I have tried to run it in the cell but the $ symbol is causing an error

Comment: @Katie these are terminal commands.

Comment: @alec_djinn Still no joy

Comment: @alec_djinn The heat appears for a second and then it disappears saying oops something went wrong where the map should be located. Do you know how I could get round this?

Comment: I'll try on my jupyter and come back to you tomorrow

Comment: @Katie I tried using `conda`  https://conda.io/miniconda.html following the oneliner found in the official documentation http://jupyter-gmaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html and it worked fine.  Can you post more details about the system you are using?

Comment: @alec_djinn I got my heat map to work thank you but do you know how I can plot green for all the latitude and longitude columns for a gp practice and then how to plot red on the map for all the crimes latitude and longitude in the map

Answer (score 0):

You should run a cell with `%matplotlib inline`. Usually people run it at the beginning of the document but in any cell would work.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem earlier, just restarted my computer and the map appeared :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with citipy & gmaps after importing and verifying installation.

Restarting my computer did not work for me but opening Jupyter via the Anaconda Prompt did (made sure to quit Anaconda first). In Anaconda Prompt(Anaconda 3) I put:

```
jupyter notebook
```

It opened a new instance of Jupyter and both dependencies worked for me. I usually opened Anaconda by searching the Anaconda Navigator in the Windows search bar but have started opening Anaconda this way and have no experienced similar issues when importing new dependencies for the first time.

Answer (score -1):

Just look for list of jupyter notebook extensions using below commands.

```
jupyter nbextension list
```

if gmaps is not in the list of extensions to include it:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension
jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix gmaps
```

If its still not showing up, try restarting jupyter notebook once.