# Plugin 'jupyter-gmaps' failed to activate

Tags: python, google-maps, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to install `gmaps 0.9.0` in my jupyter environment but when I try to run the example from [the tutorial page](https://jupyter-gmaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) it just gets stuck on "Loading widget...":

[image]

In chrome developer tools I can see something has clearly gone wrong:

> Plugin 'jupyter-gmaps' failed to activate. Error: No provider for:
> jupyter.extensions.jupyterWidgetRegistry.
> Could not instantiate widget

Here are the lines in my dockerfile that I used to build gmaps:

```
RUN pip install gmaps==0.9.0
RUN jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix gmaps && jupyter lab build
```

Here's what I've tried:

1. With and without the `%matplotlib inline` (per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47536735/my-google-heat-map-wont-appear-in-jupyter-notebook))
2. Pip-installing versions 0.9.0 and 0.8.2
3. I've read this github ticket but couldn't see anything helpful: https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps/issues/79 (they suggest restarting your computer, but I've rebuilt my docker container so that clearly hasn't helped in my case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `jupyterlab` version was 2.2.0. Updating to 3.0.14 resolved this issue for me.